# Crear usuarios con diferentes roles para cada Grupo

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Tengo una clase con el nombre Reunion (Meet), esta reunión (Meet) tiene Usuarios, pero cada usuario puede tener diferentes roles en cada Reunión.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Meet")
public class Meet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private State state;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_bet", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Bet bet;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)//, mappedBy="meet"
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

A continuacion muestro la clase User:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="rol")
    Rol rol;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "life")
    Life life;
```

En cada reunión (Meet) hay dos roles para los usuarios, el primero es Participante y el segundo es Propietario, pero yo obtengo todos los usuarios con rol: participante, como hago para que un usuario pueda tener varios roles en los diferentes grupos?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "rol": "PARTICIPANT",
    "life": "suspend"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "email": "string2",
    "rol": "PARTICIPANT",
    "life": "suspend"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un segundo modelo que tenga que usuarios corresponden con que rol en que grupo para que al ingresar al meet puedas buscar el rol que le corresponde en ese meet 
necesitas pensar en todo el sistema de autenticacion ya que requieres que el rol no se asigne hasta que entre a un meet y el rol no estara en la tabla de usuarios si no en esta segunda tabla donde tendras la relacion de que rol corresponde a que usuario en que grupo

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Te invito a leer [answer]. Podrías enriquecer tu respuesta con algo de código. Además, y no lo tomes a mal, usa signos de puntuación para separar bien las ideas. En tu respuesta no hay un solo signo de puntuación y eso dificulta entender tu respuesta. Puedes [edit] tu respuesta para mejorarala. Saludos

Comment: @Davincy si pero debo hacer otro join, otro atributo para jpa?